How can we play videos on ubuntu core machine?
I used ffmpeg snap on my ubuntu core machine to receive video packets from an ip camera and save it on my ubuntu core machine as a mp4 video file but when I am trying to play the video using ffmpeg I am unable to do that whats correct way to display the video on ubuntu core machine.
I have already tried:

Mpv connected to ubuntu-frame
ffmpeg connected to ubuntu-frame

and yes my ubuntu core is working properly with wpe-kit-kiosk using wayland.
Thanks in Advance.
